# Discount calculation based on type of buyer

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

i'm learning JavaScript and am working on a JavaScript function to calculate discount based on type of buyer i.e retailer/wholesaler & if it's cash or check payment. Here is the function

```
<script>
    function sell()
    {

    var gross,net,tax,discount,unitprice,quatity,select2,select3;

    unitprice=parseInt(form9.unitprice.value);
    quantity=parseInt(form9.quantity.value);
    select3=parseInt(form9.select3.value);
    select2=parseInt(form9.select2.value);
    gross=parseInt(form9.gross.value);

    gross=unitprice*quantity
    form9.gross.value=gross;
    tax=0.16*gross
    form9.tax.value=tax;

        if(select2='Cash' && select3='Retailer')
         discount=0.07*gross;

        else if(select2='Cash' && select3='Wholesaler')
          discount=0.1*gross;

        else if(select2='Check')
          discount=0*gross; 
    form9.discount.value=discount;



    net=(gross-(discount+tax));
    form9.net.value=net;

    }
    </script>
```

I created a dropdown menu for type of buyer, named it select2

```
<select name="select2">
          <?php
do {  
?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row_rsCustomercategory['type']?>"><?php echo $row_rsCustomercategory['type']?></option>
          <?php
} while ($row_rsCustomercategory = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCustomercategory));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($rsCustomercategory);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($rsCustomercategory, 0);
      $row_rsCustomercategory = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsCustomercategory);
  }
?>
        </select>
```

The select menu for type of sale is select3

```
<select name="select3" id="select3">
        <?php
do {  
?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_rsSaletype['type']?>"><?php echo $row_rsSaletype['type']?></option>
        <?php
} while ($row_rsSaletype = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSaletype));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($rsSaletype);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($rsSaletype, 0);
      $row_rsSaletype = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSaletype);
  }
?>
      </select>
```

Cash sales are discount at 7% retailer and 10% wholesaler, no discount for payment by check.

The Problem is that:
Upon viewing in a browser and clicking on the "Calculate" button nothing happens. Why is this?
I would appreciate any help whatsoever.

Comment: First of all: `if(select2='Cash' && select3='Retailer')`; Those need to be `==` and not a single `=`

Comment: changed it but still not working

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with your final html and js? after php has produced its output

Comment: I think you should do these calculations on the browser, since it would be easily hackable by any user (don't forget that we are also users, and we know how to read this code). I think you should solve this somehow on your *backend* or at least, on your controller. My two cents.

Comment: Think facundofarias missed the word "not"as in "I think you should NOT do these calculations on the browser" , That's a very good point facundofarias.

Comment: Actually, you should do the calculations in the browser *and also* on the back end.  Doing the calculations in the browser gives the (honest) user instant feedback with no network latency (assuming the display of the net price in the form is visible to the user) and again at the back end because JavaScript can be tampered with.

Comment: Thanks guys, i have implemented it in the backend instead. Cheers!